# Finding roots of polynomial in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Give the roots of $x^2 + x + 8$ in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z.$

My solution so far:

$f(0) = 8\bmod5 = 3,
f(1) = 10\bmod5 = 0,
f(2) = 14\bmod5 = 4,
f(3) = 20\bmod5 = 0,
f(4) = 28\bmod5 = 3.$

So the roots are $1 + 5\mathbb Z$ and $3+5\mathbb Z.$
Is this correct?

Comment: I added [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.

$x^2+x+8\equiv x^2-4x+3=(x-1)(x-3)\pmod 5.$

Since $5$ is prime, $(x-1)(x-3)\equiv0\pmod5$ means $x\equiv1$ or $x\equiv3\pmod5$.

Comment: But if we tried that to solve $x^2-3x+2=0\pmod 6$ we'd get $(x-2)(x-1)=0$ to get $x = 1,2$ but we would miss $x=4, x=5$.

Comment: $5$ is prime; $6$ is not

Comment: Well, yes..., that was my point.  Do you think that a student at the OP's level should by told to do this without any caveats as to how and when it is valid and when it is not?

Comment: Ok, @fleablood, I edited to mention that caveat